# How to select records for a given date from SQL Server system-versioned table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2019

I am using SQL Server 2019.

I am using a system-versioned table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    LastName varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    -- Some other columns
    StartTime datetime2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    EndTime datetime2(7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL, 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime,EndTime) 
) 
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON(HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
```

The names of the table and the columns are changed, but this is how the table is created.

My question is pretty simple, but I can not find satisfying answer.

This table is available for the end users and one of the options is to provide DateTime `SearchDate` and I want to return all records in the `Employee` table which are made this Date.

However, even though the user may send not just Date but also Time the response should contain all records made the given Date in `SearchDate` and ignore the time.

Basically the queries which I found relate to system-versioned table are pretty simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employee
FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN @SearchDate AND ???
WHERE dbo.Employee.EmployeeID=2
```

After my research what I found is that I can take advantage of the system-versioned table and search *after* given `DateTime` or search in given DateTime range for which I found several different syntax which seems like at the end they provide the same result. Sadly, I wasn't able to find something built in which will search the entire date.

So my question is - is there way to take advantage of the fact that I am using system-versioned tabled and filter all records for a given Date no matter the Time component.

If not, I think that a decent workaround would be to use this clause `FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN`. As input I get `DECLARE @SearchDate DATETIME2(7)` so I would accept as an answer also a query which will the this `@SearchDate` and transform it in a way where I can extract the correct format of a DateTime which will indicate the very start of the `@SearchDate` date and the very end of the `@SearchDate` date so I can use those value in the `BETWEEN` syntax?

Comment: Use Day() function.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `DATEADD` and `CAST` to get the start and end of the day

```sql
DECLARE @startDate datetime2(7) = CAST(@SearchDate AS date);
DECLARE @endDate datetime2(7) = DATEADD(day, 1, @startDate);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employee
FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
WHERE dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = 2;
```

Note that for `BETWEEN`, the start point is exclusive and the end point is inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've missed the fact the start i exclusive when using `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Generally you should do date range queries with one end exclusive and the other inclusive. Otherwise you either miss dates that fall on the boundary or you count them twice (when querying the next range)